# Is there any difference between 使ってみましょう and 使いましょう？

Tags: usage

使ってみましょう and 使いましょう

Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: ↓「て-form + みる」means "try ~~ing", no? eg:「使ってみる」= "try using"  cf:「使おうとする」= "try to use"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the しょう forms of two different verbs.

使ってみましょう is the polite variant of 使ってみよう. The root verb is 使ってみる (使ってみます), which means "to try using"

使いましょう is the polite variant of 使おう which is the volitional form of 使う (使います) which means "to use"

The places where you use these two are different.

For instance, 冷蔵庫を使いましょう = let's use the refrigerator -- we know it works and we are going to use it.

whereas 冷蔵庫を使ってみましょう = let's try to use the refrigerator -- we are going to test out the fridge somewhere we have not been for a while (like a cabin) and hope that it works for what we want.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! I hope these all helps others as well. And thank you for the two other answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

使ってみましょう is a trial. The meaning: "Try to use" 使いましょう just mean "Use".

Answer (score 1):

使ってみましょう - let's try to use it / let's use it and see what happens (contextual)

使いましょう - let's use it